# LOW DISK SPACE ERROR

Tags: dual-boot

I have both SSD hard disk and normal HDD hard disk in my computer. the operating system is windows 10 which is installed in SSD drive. I am trying to install ubuntu 16.04.1 alongside with the windows 10 but before the installation process starts I receive LOW DISK SPACE error. I have more than 100 GB free space on my SSD drive and more than 700 GB free space in my HDD. I did partitioning but I don't know why I receive this error. any help ?

Comment: You need unallocated space, space that is not part of any partition, not free space inside partitions.

Comment: thank you for response, I have unallocated space when I did partitioning. the problem is as soon as I want to install Ubuntu, I get the error. In the first step of installation which is choosing the language. I was wondering if this error is due to hardware problem or UEFI(BIOS) setting.

Comment: In a the live session, open GParted and take screenshots of your drives. The edit and update your question with them.